# Removing "require-dev" section from composer.json

Tags: magento2, composer

Is this a sane thing to do on Production site?

```
"require-dev": {
       "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.2.0",
       "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.14.0",
       "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
       "magento/magento-coding-standard": "~3.0.0",
       "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "2.4.5",
       "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
       "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
       "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
       "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
       "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.4.0"
},
```

And if we don't need that, then "autoload-dev" section is also not needed?

```
"autoload-dev": {
       "psr-4": {
           "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
           "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
           "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
           "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
           "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
   }
},
```

The problem is that every time I run composer update it re-downloads the dev repos and re-installs them.

After

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I run

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Which takes up a bunch of time when the site is on maintenance mode.

Just testing locally on my DEV environment it seems to be working ok.

But, I thought to ask maybe there are some other issues I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove unused require-dev packages

```
"behat/behat": "^3.0",  
"phpspec/phpspec": "^2.5",  
"symfony/var-dumper": "^3.0",   
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.2"
```

Also in your required attribute make sure to keep minimal dependencies. Remove unused packages here

You can only keep

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.3"
},
```